# While updating video drivers something went wrong, get only a "initramfs" prompt but can't use keyboard!

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, chroot

I was trying to use "ubuntu-drivers autoinstall" to upgrade my Nvidia drivers to 440, when the system (Lubuntu 18.04LTS, Dell Studio XPS 8100, 16GB ram, 1TB hard disk) just hung.  I went out, came back hours later, still nothing.  Finally I did a hard reboot and while Grub will allow me to select a boot, I end up getting a very disturbing text screen and an "initramfs" prompt...but the keyboard doesn't work.

I have since booted up from a live USB, but can someone perhaps walk me through what I need to do to get the drivers working again?  This has been traumatic to say the least.

I believe I will need to mount the hard drive and chroot it, then perform a few operations...just don't know exactly what I need to do.  If anyone knows this procedure I'd love some help.  Thank you so much in advance for anything you can offer.

Comment: @K7AAY Thank you, yes...sorry, should have added that from the beginning!  It's there now!